# Find a word inbetween other letters Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I need my program to be able to distinguish a word even when it has a few characters inbetween some of the letters.
For example, say it was given "guitar".
I need it to know when it sees: "g#2f4f4f;uitar"
Any quick way of doing this?
All help appreciated.

Comment: Use regex and remove special characters and numerals.But, then also you will have gfffuitar and it will not match guitar.

Comment: `#2f4f4f;` looks like a color code usually seen in a html or css source. `#...;` pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regular expressions ([good site here](https://regex101.com))

```
def match_with_noise(word, noisy_word):
    return re.match("(.*)".join(word), noisy_word)
```

This returns a [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#search-vs-match) object that is easy to deal with:

```
>>> match_with_noise("guitar", "g0923874uitar")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='g0923874uitar'>
```

For example, use `.groups()` to get the stuff that isn't supposed to be there:

```
>>> match_with_noise("guitar", "g0923874uitar").groups()
('0923874', '', '', '', '')
```

Comment: Not a full answer but a definitely helpful bit of info. I should be able to use this and just remove the noise this pulls. Cheers!